# Turning minutes into hours if necessary in php

Tags: php

I tried this:

```
$total_time_minutes = '132';
$total_time_hours = '26';

if($total_time_minutes > 60)
{
    $time = strtotime( $minutes . ' minutes'); 

    $time = date('H:i', $time); 

    $time = explode(':', $time); 

    $hours = $time[0]; 
    $minutes = $time[1]; 

    $total_time_hours += $hours;
    $total_time_minutes = $minutes;
}
```

if i output $total_time_hours and $total_time_minutes from this it will give me: 26:44, which is incorrect.

It should give me 28:12, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$total_time_minutes = '132';
$total_time_hours = '26';

if($total_time_minutes > 60)
{
    $hours = floor($total_time_minutes / 60);
    $minutes = $total_time_minutes % 60;

    $total_time_hours += $hours;
    $total_time_minutes = $minutes;
}
```

`date()` function if for unix timestamp formatting. What you have is not a valid unix timestamp (yes, I understand it could be that small, but not in this particular case)